# page creator to leave comments ONLY

Tags: plugins, comments, permissions

I am trying to set it so that the person who created a Page is the ONLY one who can comment on that particular page. This will be a logged in person.  I haven't had any luck with Role Editor Plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a way to do this via one of the meta cap filters, but off the top of my head you could use the `comments_open` filter to check if the currently logged in user is the author of the post and change the output of the `comments_open()` function accordingly.

I'm on the patio, so can't test, but something like this should work:

```
add_filter( 'comments_open', 'wpse158190_comments_open', 10, 2 );
function wpse158190_comments_open( $open, $post_id ) {
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  $post = get_post( $post_id ); // 'global $post;' may also work here
  if ( $current_user->ID == $post->post_author ) return TRUE;
}
```

Edit:

As noted in comments, the above will also disallow anyone but the author from *seeing* comments.

Looking through the `comment_form()` function in core, I don't see a very clean way to accomplish this. You could run a late hook of the `comment_form_default_fields` filter in order to remove the fields:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'wpse158195_comment_form_default_fields', 99 );
function wpse158195_comment_form_default_fields( $fields ) {
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  $post = get_post( $post_id ); // 'global $post;' may also work here
  if ( $current_user->ID != $post->post_author ) unset $fields;
  return $fields
}
```

However, I suspect this will leave a useless "Leave a reply" heading and "Post Comment" button. You could *hide* these by injecting some CSS on the page via the `comment_form_before` action:

```
add_action( 'comment_form_before', 'wpse158195_comment_form_before' );
function 158195_comment_form_before() {
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  $post = get_post( $post_id ); // 'global $post;' may also work here
  if ( $current_user->ID != $post->post_author ) : ?>
    <style type="text/css">
      #respond.comment-respond { display: none; }
    </style>
  <?php endif;
}
```

Comment: Add it to your theme's functions.php file

Comment: If you want it as a plugin, just put it in a new file in the plugins folder, with the appropriate header information included.

Comment: yeah maybe I should have been more specific. I need the author of the page to be the ONLY one to be able to leave a comment on their own page but I need EVERYONE to be able to view this comment but without the ability to reply or leave a comment themselves. Is there a read only filter or something like that?

Comment: Ah okay - I've updated my answer.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to wrap the CSS in the same conditional logic; updated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is working 100%. Here is the total plugin if anyone else needs it...

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'wpse158195_comment_form_default_fields', 99 );
function wpse158195_comment_form_default_fields( $fields ) {
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  $post = get_post( $post_id ); // 'global $post;' may also work here
  if ( $current_user->ID != $post->post_author ) unset ($fields);
  return $fields;
}

add_action( 'comment_form_before', 'wpse158195_comment_form_before' );
function wpse158195_comment_form_before() {
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  $post = get_post( $post_id ); // 'global $post;' may also work here
  if ( $current_user->ID != $post->post_author ) : ?>
    <style type="text/css">
      #respond.comment-respond { display: none; }
      .comment-reply-link { display: none; }
    </style>
  <?php endif;
}
```

Thank You so much karpstrucking

Comment: When you add code to the editor, highlight it, and then click on the `{}` sign just above the text box. This will add your code in a code block as in my edit

Comment: glad I could help!